# Firebase - Angular / I'm not able to display my result with orderByChild method

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a database for my users organized like this :

```
Database
 - Users
  - Id (determined thanks to the push method)
    - email
    - firstName
    - ptsTotal
    - ...
```

I want to use the orderByChild method to establish a ranking of my users according to ptsTotal (which is a number of points in a game).

Below is my component in Angular :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from '../../services/users.service';
import {User} from '../../models/user.model';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-total',
  templateUrl: './total.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./total.component.scss']
})
export class TotalComponent implements OnInit {

  usersRanking:User[] = [];
  tableau:any[];

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRanking();
  }

  getRanking(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('ptsTotal')
    .on('value',(data)=>{
      data.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            this.tableau.push(childData);

      });

    });
}
}
```

Here is my output in the console
[image: Here is my output in the console]

My Html is not working. I use a ngFor and the result on my page is 6 lines (And I just have 4 users).

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

firstName : - LastName : - Number of Points :

(Html code below)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2>Users Ranking</h2>
    <div class="list-group"
        *ngFor="let user of usersRanking | keyvalue async">
        <p>firstName : {{user.value.firstName}} - LastName : {{user.value.lastName}} - Number of Points : {{user.value.ptsTotal}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

P.S : Here is the console when I'm using "value" instead of "child_added". My users are not ordered :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `value` event:

```
tableau:any[] = [];

getRanking(){
  firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('ptsTotal')
  .on('value',(data)=>{
  data.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    this.tableau.push(childData);
   });
});
```

Then use `forEach()` to loop inside the data and then add the data to the array `tableau`, and use it inside the html.

Comment: without orderbychild do you get the values on the screen?

Comment: Yes when I just retrieve my data, it's working but the output in the console is different

Comment: I'm able to see the data (if I use {{user.value.firstName}} - but data are not ordered according to my ptsTotal

Comment: it will order it in ascending order

Comment: It should :) because right now, it's not ordered. The first is 70, the second 65, the third 100 and the last 0. I'm adding a picture to show you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216416/discussion-between-alexandre-deschateaux-and-peter-haddad).